# Why Authorization Code is necessary in Oauth2?

Tags: http, oauth, authorization, oauth-2.0

Authorization Code Grant is one of the four authorization grant types in OAuth2. In Implicit Grant, authorization token is directly sent back in response, but in Authorization Code Grant, code is sent back in response, which will then be used for retrieving token from authorization server.

My question is, why Authorization Code is necessary for Authorization Code Grant, instead of directly sending back token as is done in Implicit Grant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the authorization code grant, the exchange of an authorization code for a token happens on the server-side (i.e. not directly in the browser). This way the client secret and token can be kept more "safely" on the server. Read [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.2) about the "simplifications" the implicit flow makes at the expense of some security implications